# Date Time Picker issue in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I would like to display DateTime picker in my App, so I'm write below code to display DateTime Picker, every thing is working fine but in Android device date is not displayed properly.

```
Form dialogtimeForm     = new Form("Set time");
                    dialogtimeForm.setUIID("workersListForm");
                    if(!Constants.PLATFORMNAME.equals(Display.getInstance().getPlatformName())){
                            spinner = new DateTimeSpinner(){
                            @Override
                            protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
                                return new Dimension(460, 180);
                            }
                       };
                    } else{
                        spinner = new DateTimeSpinner();
                    }
                    spinner.setShowMeridiem(true);
                    spinner.setMinuteStep(1);
                    int hours               = 0;
                    int minutes             = 0;
                    boolean showMeridiem    = false;
                    Date date               = null;
                    timeValue               = data;

                    if(timeValue != null && !"".equals(timeValue)){
                        hours               = Util.getHours(timeValue);
                        minutes             = Util.getMinutes(timeValue);
                        showMeridiem        = Util.getAmPm(timeValue);
                        date                = Util.getDate(DBActuallCallDate);
                    }
                    if(hours > 12){
                        hours               = hours -12;
                        showMeridiem        = true;
                    }

                    spinner.setCurrentHour(hours);
                    spinner.setCurrentMinute(minutes);
                    spinner.setCurrentMeridiem(showMeridiem);
                    spinner.setCurrentDate(date);

                    dialogtimeForm.add(spinner);
                    Dialog dialog               = new Dialog();
                    dialog.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true);

                    commands[0]                 = new Command(Constants.SETCOMMAND){
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            int hour            = spinner.getCurrentHour();
                            int minute          = spinner.getCurrentMinute();
                            boolean meridiem    = spinner.isCurrentMeridiem();
                            String time         = Util.timeConversion(hour, minute, meridiem);
                            String workerTime   = Util.getFormatedTimeValue(time, spinner.getCurrentDate());
                            callInField.setText(time);
                            roasterDao = new RoasterDao();
                            if(flag.equals(Constants.ACTUALCALLOUTFLAG))
                                roasterDao.updateActualCallOutTime(workerTime, serialId);
                            else
                                roasterDao.updateActualCallInTime(workerTime, serialId);

                            dialog.dispose();
                            if(ApplicationScopeBean.dialogShow){
                                if(flag.equals(Constants.ACTUALCALLOUTFLAG))
                                   Dialog.show("Alert", workerName+Constants.CHECKOUTSUCCESSFULLY+time,"ok",null);
                                else
                                    Dialog.show("Alert", workerName+Constants.CHECKINSUCCESSFULLY+time,"ok",null);
                            } else{
                                if(flag.equals(Constants.ACTUALCALLOUTFLAG))
                                    Toast.makeText(RoasterApp.getContext(), workerName+Constants.CHECKOUTSUCCESSFULLY+time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                else
                                    Toast.makeText(RoasterApp.getContext(), workerName+Constants.CHECKINSUCCESSFULLY+time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            Container unScheduledWorkerTableContainer = setUnScheduledWorkerTable();
                            unScheduledWorkerTableContainer.setUIID("unScheduledWorkerTable");
                            unScheduledWorkerBoxContainer.removeAll();
                            unScheduledWorkerBoxContainer.add(unScheduledWorkerTableContainer);
                            unScheduledWorkersForm.revalidate();
                        }
                    };
                    commands[1] = new Command(Constants.CLEARCOMMAND){
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog();
                            dialog1.setUIID("listDialog");
                            String clearCallOutDialog   = Constants.CLEARCALLOUTDIALOG;
                            String clearCallInDialog    = Constants.CLEARCALLINDIALOG;
                            dialog.dispose();
                            FlowLayout centerLayout     = new FlowLayout();
                            centerLayout.setAlign(Component.CENTER);
                            centerLayout.setValign(Component.TOP);
                            Container flowContainer     = new Container(centerLayout);
                            Container boxXAxisLayout    = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
                            Button okButton = new Button(Constants.OKCOMMAND);
                            okButton.setUIID("dialogCloseButton");
                            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                                    roasterDao          = new RoasterDao();
                                    if(flag.equals(Constants.ACTUALCALLOUTFLAG))
                                        roasterDao.updateActualCallOutTime("", serialId);
                                    else
                                        roasterDao.updateActualCallInTime("", serialId);
                                    callInField.setText("");
                                    dialog1.dispose();
                                    dialog.dispose();
                                    Container unScheduledWorkerTableContainer = setUnScheduledWorkerTable();
                                    unScheduledWorkerTableContainer.setUIID("unScheduledWorkerTable");
                                    unScheduledWorkerBoxContainer.removeAll();
                                    unScheduledWorkerBoxContainer.add(unScheduledWorkerTableContainer);
                                    unScheduledWorkersForm.revalidate();
                                }
                            });
                            Button close                 = new Button(Constants.CANCELCOMMAND);
                            close.setUIID("dialogCloseButton");
                            close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                                    dialog1.dispose();
                                    dialog.dispose();
                                    Container unScheduledWorkerTableContainer = setUnScheduledWorkerTable();
                                    unScheduledWorkerTableContainer.setUIID("unScheduledWorkerTable");
                                    unScheduledWorkerBoxContainer.removeAll();
                                    unScheduledWorkerBoxContainer.add(unScheduledWorkerTableContainer);
                                    unScheduledWorkersForm.revalidate();
                                }
                            });

                            boxXAxisLayout.add(okButton);
                            boxXAxisLayout.add(close);
                            flowContainer.add(boxXAxisLayout);

                            dialog1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE));
                            String dataLabelString  = "";
                            if(flag.equals(Constants.ACTUALCALLOUTFLAG))
                                dataLabelString     = clearCallOutDialog;
                            else
                                dataLabelString     = clearCallInDialog;
                            Label dataLabel         = new Label(dataLabelString);
                            dataLabel.setUIID("confirmDialogBody");
                            dialog1.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, dataLabel);
                            dialog1.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, flowContainer);
                            dialog1.show();
                        }
                    };
                    commands[2] = new Command(Constants.CANCELCOMMAND){
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            dialog.dispose();
                            Container unScheduledWorkerTableContainer = setUnScheduledWorkerTable();
                            unScheduledWorkerTableContainer.setUIID("unScheduledWorkerTable");
                            unScheduledWorkerBoxContainer.removeAll();
                            [![enter image description here][1]][1]unScheduledWorkerBoxContainer.add(unScheduledWorkerTableContainer);
                            unScheduledWorkersForm.revalidate();
                        }
                    };
                    dialog.show("", dialogtimeForm, commands);
```

please find screenshots.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Picker API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html) will display native date/time UI on supported platforms. Date, Time, Numbers and Strings are supported on Android but DateTime is only supported on iOS so you are seeing a "fallback" UI.

There is no native equivalent for "DateTime" on Android so you would need